# C++で外部クラスを使用したプログラムがコンパイルできない

Tags: c++

C++初心者です。複数のファイルを取り込んだプログラムがコンパイルできず、その理由もわかりません。

A.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    B test;
    test.show(*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include <string>

class B {
public:
    void show(std::string);
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    void show(const char *var) {
        cout << var << endl;
    }
};
```

これでコンパイル

```
g++ -o a.exe A.cpp
```

すると

```
/tmp/ccGn41oP.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x4c): `B::show(std::string)' に対する定義されていない参照です
/tmp/ccGn41oP.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x4c): 再配置がオーバーフローしないように切り詰められました: R_X86_64_PC32 (未定義シンボル `B::show(std::string)' に対して)
collect2: エラー: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました
```

こうなってしまいます。
これはどういうエラーなんでしょうか。
こんな初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、教えてください。

> ご回答について

ご回答ありがとうございます。
コンパイルの流れを理解していませんでした。
おっしゃる通り、

```
g++ -c B.cpp
```

を実行したところ、

```
$ g++ -c B.cpp
B.cpp:8:7: エラー: ‘class B’ が再定義されています
 class B {
       ^
In file included from B.cpp:1:0:
B.h:8:7: エラー: ‘class B’ の前の定義
 class B {
       ^
```

となってしまったため、プロトタイプの実装本体はクラス宣言しないのかと思い、
下記に変更して再度実行しました。

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void show(const char *var) {
    cout << var << endl;
}
```

これで"B.o"というファイルが生成され、改めて

```
g++ -o A.exe A.cpp
```

を実行したものの、エラーの内容が変わりませんでした。

> sayuri さん

ちなみにですが・・・
引数を

```
void show(std::string var);
```

に統一し、

```
g++ -c B.cpp
g++ -o A.exe A.cpp
```

を行うと

```
$ g++ -o a.exe A.cpp
/tmp/ccSVMoNA.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x4c): `B::show(std::string)' に対する定義されていない参照です
/tmp/ccSVMoNA.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x4c): 再配置がオーバーフローしないように切り詰められました: R_X86_64_PC32 (未定義シンボル `B::show(std::string)' に対して)
collect2: エラー: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました
```

というエラーになります。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/pknight/20090826/1251303641

このブログを見ると、この場合はtemplate関数の場合ですが、
「この関数は使われていないから.objを生成しても実態がないのでA.cppからは実装が見えません」
というようなことが書いてありました。
もしこれと同様の現象が起きているのだとすると、今回show()関数はグローバルメンバ関数ではなくクラスメンバ関数なのでA.cppから見ることはできない
ということになってしまうんでしょうか。
言語仕様をほとんどよくわかっていないので、さすがにそんなことはないんじゃないかと思いますが・・・

C++開発者の方も、実行ファイル1つで完結するプログラムなんてそうそう書かないと思いますが、
皆さんはどうやって外部関数を参照しているのかわかりません。

Comment: 既に回答されていますが`void show(const char *var) {` は、`void B::show(std::string){` のようにクラスＢのメソッドとして書く（引数の型もそろえて）必要があります。

Comment: sayuriさんの回答にてコメントしましたが、そのあたりの確認は行いました。

Comment: こちらで確認したところでは、問題無くコンパイル＆実行できました。

Comment: `g++ A.cpp B.cpp -o A.exe` とするか`g++ B.cpp -c` の後`g++ -o A.exe A.cpp B.o` としてコンパイルしてみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事動きました。コンパイル方法が間違っていたんですね。
承認したいんですがコメントだとできないんですがどうすればいいでしょう・・・

Comment: @sayuri さんの回答を承認すればいいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C言語及びC++言語には宣言と定義の２つが存在します。
B.hに

```
class B {
public:
    void show(std::string);
};
```

と宣言した場合、B.cppに記述すべきこれに対応する定義は

```
void B::show(std::string){
    ...
}
```

となります。C言語と異なりC++言語には関数オーバーロードがあるため、引数を完全に一致させる必要があります。また `void B::show(std::string)` と `void show(std::string)` も別関数です。

Comment: さきほどオーバーロードに気付いて、引数については修正しました。
また、B.cppからはBクラスのメンバ関数だとわかるのか？と思い、B.cppでのオーバーライド宣言をB::show()にも変更してみましたが、結局それら一通りを試してもうまくいきませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

コンパイル、コンパイルといいますが、厳密には以下のフェーズに分かれています。
　(1)コンパイル：ソースコードからオブジェクトファイルを生成
　(2)リンク：オブジェクトファイルを紐づけて実行形式ファイルを生成

つまり、
　[A.cpp, B.cpp, B.h] --(1)--> [A.o, B.o] --(2)--> [A.exe]
ということです。

で、上記のエラーメッセージを見る限りリンクのフェーズでエラーが発生しています。
内容を見るとB::Showが、恐らくはB.obj見つかりません、という事ですね。
(1)はソースコード単位で行われます。
ですので、B.objが作成されていないのでは？、と見受けられます。。
　g++ -c B.cpp
を実施すれば解決するかと。

Answer (score 1):

ソースファイルが複数に分かれている場合, ビルド手順は以下のいずれかの方法になります.

A. ソースファイルを個別にコンパイルし, 後でリンクする.

```
g++ -c A.cpp
g++ -c B.cpp
g++ -o a.exe A.o B.o
```

最初の2行で, それぞれ A.o と B.o を生成します. 「-c」オプションをつけた場合, 拡張子を.oに置き換えたものがデフォルトの出力ファイル名になります.
3行目で, リンクします.
規模が大きいとこの方法が主流です. 下の方法と比べて, ソースを一部変更した後の再コンパイル・ビルドがです.

B. まとめてコンパイル, リンクする.

```
g++ -o a.exe A.cpp B.cpp
```

1行でかけるので手軽ですが, 中間のオブジェクトファイルが残らないので, 一部を修正した場合でも両方のソースをコンパイルし直すことになり, 時間がかかります.

ソースコードにエラーがあり, sayuriさんの回答にもあるとおり, B.cppを以下のように修正する必要があります.

```
#include "B.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void B::show(std::string var) {
  cout << var << endl;
}
```